# Triple Accessing Element

Tags: haskell

If in Haskell I had a tuple:

```
x = (1, 2)
```

I could use fst x to retrieve 1 and snd x to retrieve 2

I was wondering, if I had a triple:

```
y = (1, 2, 3)
```

is there a similar function I could use?

Answer (score 10):

You need to write your own extractor functions:

```
extractFirst :: (a, b, c) -> a
extractFirst (a,_,_) = a
```

The `fst` and `snd` functions are only applicable for a tuple i.e `(a, b)`

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a built-in one. If there were, you'd need a whole lot of them `1of2`, `2of2`, `1of4`, `4of7`. Instead of getting them all as built-in functions, `fst` and `snd` are defined specially and for most other cases we use pattern matching:

```
4of7 (_, _, _, x, _, _, _) = x
```

The `lens` library, a fairly popular advanced library, does provide all of these by using clever typeclasses.

```
3of4 = view _3
4of4 = view _4
3of7 = view _3
...
```

But that generality comes at a fairly steep complexity price.

Comment: Complexity in what sense? Using those specific things is not complex, but it does introduce a lot of dependencies, which may change the computational complexity class of cabal builds.

Comment: The type of `view _3` is exactly what you'd expect it to be but more than you might want. You could nail it down with the `*ofN` bits but then you're actually no better than pattern matching and a whole lot of dependencies in.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, the way to go is pattern matching. However, for the sake of completeness I wanted to mention that you could simply use a lambda function:

```
head $ map (\(a, b, c) -> a) (y : [])
```